# Key hold not registered after xkbmap language switch

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys, hardware, i3-wm, xkb

I'm using i3wm with ubuntu 16.04. To switch between languages, I have following in my `.config/i3/config`:

`exec_always setxkbmap "us,ru" ",winkeys" "grp:alt_shift_toggle"`

**The problem is:** I press and hold both <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, the input language switches, then I release alt (but still hold shift), and shift is not registering (as if I'm not holding it, even though I am).

**Expected behaviour:** Press and hold both <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, release alt, press any key (whilst holding shift), the key output should be upper-case.

**Actual behaviour:** the key output is lower-case (as if I'm not holding shift, even though I am)

This works as expected on another computer with the same i3wm, same ubuntu 16.04, same keyboard even. Is this somehow hardware related? Any possible fix for this? Thanks

Comment: Where did you test the output? Terminal, text editor,... ?

Comment: @danzel just about everywhere. Both terminal, text editors, even commands. In the above scenario, Win+Shift+R works as Shift+R (resize instead of reload)

Comment: Which type of keyboard? USB, PS/2, bluetooth? Was it connected the same way on both computers? Try to disable the shortcut and see if the behaviour changes. You can also use `xev` or `evtest` to see if the keypresses/releases are registered at all.